# PHP - SQL select first column with no data

Tags: php, sql

How do I find the first column with no data?

```
//column pet1='dog'
//column pet2=''
//column pet3=''
//column pet4='cat'


if($F=="getempty"){
    $uid=$_GET["uid"];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT pet1,pet2,pet3,pet4 FROM a WHERE uid='".$uid."' AND pet1='' OR pet2='' OR pet3=''OR pet4=''");    
    while($column=mysql_fetch_field($sql)){
        $empty=$column->name;
        echo json_encode(array("empty"=>$empty));
        }
    }else{}
```

I keep trying but so far it just returns all column names if one is empty

pet1,pet2,pet3,pet4

Comment: `"SELECT DISTINCT pet1,pet2,pet3,pet4 FROM a WHERE uid='".$uid."' AND (pet1='' OR pet2='' OR pet3=''OR pet4='')"` ( ) around OR's I think

Comment: @Bjørne_Malmanger this still returns all 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DISTINCT` will combine the rows which are exactly alike (having all the selected columns the same) and return them.

To get the name of the first empty column, use a query like:

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN pet1 = '' THEN 'pet1'
    WHEN pet2 = '' THEN 'pet2'
    WHEN pet3 = '' THEN 'pet3'
    WHEN pet4 = '' THEN 'pet4'
  ELSE NULL
 END AS firstempty
FROM a
WHERE uid = '$uid';
```

The idea is that the `CASE` statement checks each one in order, and finding an empty one returns the column name without checking the rest of them.

Don't forget to escape `$uid` with `mysql_real_escape_string()` before passing it to the query.

```
$uid = mysql_real_escape_string($uid);
```

Since we're now getting the column name inside a field called `firstempty`, we'll also need to change the way it's fetched:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
     $empty = $row['firstempty'];
     echo json_encode(array("empty"=>$empty));
}
```

Comment: this returns {"empty":"firstempty"} whereas, I need {"empty":"pet2"}

Comment: @BenMuircroft Oops, I didn't account for how you were fetching the result. See my addition above to change the way the fetch is done. Should work now...