# SQL - Moving or updating data to first empty column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables with following data and I'm using Microsoft SQL Express to manage them:

Table1

```
Name  Col1  ColSwitch
Row1  3     NULL
Row2  7     NULL
Row3  5     True
Row4  12    True
Row5  2     True
```

Table2

```
Name  Col1  Col2  Col3
Row3  3     NULL  NULL
Row4  4     10    NULL
Row6  2     3     9
Row7  6     NULL  NULL
```

---

I'm looking to move rows from Table1 to Table2 when **ColSwitch is set to True**.
I can successfully do this with following:

```
INSERT Table2 (Name, ColN)
    SELECT Name, Col1
    FROM Table1
    WHERE ColSwitch LIKE 'True'
```

But my issue comes in when I need to select the first empty column when updating existing entries (Row3 and Row4 in example).
I found an example where *[CASE WHEN ELSE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9506087)* was utilized, but I would like to avoid having to use PHP at this point in time.

Simply using the provided method without PHP will fill the first column with the column name that is NULL. *(Below)*

```
SELECT Name,
CASE
    WHEN Col1 IS NULL THEN 'Col1'
    WHEN Col2 IS NULL THEN 'Col2'
  ELSE 'Col3'
 END as ColN
FROM Table2
```

---

Desired output would be where first NULL field in Table2 is replaced by the value from Table1, or alternatively adding to Col3 if all are already filled.

Output assuming *Row3 = 5*, *Row4 = 12* and *Row5 = 2* from the original tables on top.

```
Name  Col1  Col2  Col3
Row3  3     5     NULL
Row4  4     10    12
Row5  2     NULL  NULL
Row6  2     3     9
Row7  6     NULL  NULL
```

Is this possible to do with just simple SQL? If yes, please explain how to best approach this and if possible, provide an example :)

Comment: Show desired output for your input

Comment: The [MERGE statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) allows you to do INSERTS and UPDATES in a single query.

Comment: Are all the columns NULL starting with first NULL? Or could there be NULL in column 3 and value in column 4?

Comment: There are only 3 columns, 1st column can be NULL as well in certain scenarios but it would not be part in this query usually.
Output would be simply replacing the first NULL with the Col1 value from Table1 (alternatively adding to the Col3 if all are already filled; there are only total of 3 columns)

Comment: Also I wasnt clear, but yes Jakub, all columns other than Name are NULL by default, unless replaced by value. All columns should also be filled in order, so Col1 shouldnt be NULL if Col2 has a value in Table2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design leads to complicated case, consider redisigning your solution. 
Because you didn't describe details of your overall problem, I could not help here.

Solution 1:
Genarate dynamic SQL and execute it. Because Column is dynamic you have to generate one INSERT per row.

```
SELECT @query='construct insert command text here' FROM Table2,Table1
EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Solution 2:
If your set of columns is limited you can use MERGE command.
You should add your conditions.

```
MERGE INTO Table2
USING Table1 
ON Table1.Name=Table2.Name
  WHEN MATCHED AND Table2.Col1 IS NULL
    THEN UPDATE SET Col1=Table1.Col1
  WHEN MATCHED AND Table2.Col2 IS NULL
    THEN UPDATE SET Col2=Table1.Col1
  WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    THEN INSERT (Name,Col1) VALUES Table1.Name, Table1.Col1
```

Comment: Thanks Patrik, currently this is my overall solution and it is not tied to anything else yet, so the only problem I'm having is creating SQL query to move data from Table1 to Table2. I am only starting my database project here so I'm open for better alternatives to the database design. Of course it would be preferred to be able to use current design.
I'm looking at the solution 2, but to me it seems like this would require me to have filtered the list to only show *ColSwitch = True* before executing this one, am I wrong?

Comment: You don't need filter before. Add your condition to ON clause together with  excluding reows you dont weant to insert in WHEN NOT MATCHED clause.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work: "An action of type 'WHEN MATCHED' cannot appear more than once in a 'UPDATE' clause of a MERGE statement."
I tried searching for ways to insert OR into WHEN THEN ELSE, but it doesnt seem to work in a way that would be applicable for my situation.

Comment: WHEN MATCHED AND Table2.Col1 IS NULL
    THEN UPDATE SET Col1=Table1.Col1
  WHEN MATCHED AND Table2.Col2 IS NULL
    THEN UPDATE SET Col2=Table1.Col1 - this causes the error if you read the error message that I attached. You can only have one of these.

Comment: I will consider your solution 1 as an answer. I'm going with redesigning the Tables to allow better implementation until someone provides a better logic.